# Combine Similar ASP.NET MVC Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two very similar ASP.NET MVC routes, provided below.

Is there anyway to combine the two routes and place a conditional statement so that (1) any requests to "logs/email/" goes to the EmailLogsController, and requests to "logs/user/" goes to the UserLogsController?

```
// URL: /areax/logs/email/
// URL: /areax/logs/email/details/51
// URL: /areax/logs/email/details/117
context.MapRouteLowercase(
    "AreaX.Log.Email",
    "areax/logs/email/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "EmailLogs",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    new[] { ControllerNamespaces.AreaX }
);

// URL: /areax/logs/user/
// URL: /areax/logs/user/details/1
// URL: /areax/logs/user/details/10
context.MapRouteLowercase(
    "AreaX.Log.User",
    "areax/logs/user/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "UserLogs",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    new[] { ControllerNamespaces.AreaX }
);
```

As it stands they don't look very DRY.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/3303801/… – Stefano Altieri just now edit

Comment: Thanks @StefanoAltieri - I was hoping for a simpler solution given the nature of the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer... see if it can work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can rename your controller (removing the Log suffix) you can try using the {controller} keyword:

```
    context.MapRouteLowercase(
    "AreaX.Log.Email",
    "areax/logs/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    new[] { ControllerNamespaces.AreaX }
);
```

Comment: serry.. doesn't compile... givi me a minute

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303801/how-to-achieve-a-dynamic-controller-and-action-method-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: That was in my original solution but the requirement to name the URL like this: /areax/logs/user/details/10 as opposed to this: /areax/logs/userlogs/details/10 (note the repeated "logs") means this answer isn't quite right. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Bern as suggested by Stefano, remove the "Logs" suffix and you should be fine.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but what you're suggesting is that I change my URL naming requirement to accommodate a suggested solution. If there is now way to address the requirement using MVC routing techniques then that's the answer I'll settle for. And even if I remove the "Logs" suffix that raises other issues, i.e. "UserLogsController" becomes "UserController" which isn't actually correct.