# How do override ASP.NET Core's controller naming convention?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core. The convention is that the routing system considers a `FooController` class to be a controller with the name `Foo`.

I need to override this convention. I want to do something like this:

```
[ControllerName("Bar")]
public class SomeArbitraryName : Controller {
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class SomeArbitraryName : Controller("Bar") {
}
```

Is that possible somehow?

**EDIT: No that linked "duplicate" question is not for ASP.NET Core!**

Comment: Use routes in `Startup` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change ASP.NET MVC Controller Name in URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344450/how-to-change-asp-net-mvc-controller-name-in-url)

Comment: You can name your controller type whatever you want. Assuming you registered the default route, `/SomeArbitraryName` would work just fine (and the `controller` token in your `RouteData` would be "SomeArbitraryName").

Comment: That is what route prefixes are for

Comment: @haim770 No I don't want "SomeArbitraryName", I want "Bar".

Comment: @Nkosi No that is not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @grokky Attribute routing still exists in core.`[Route("Bar")]public class SomeArbitraryName : Controller {...}`

Comment: @grokky, Then just add `[Route("Bar")]` in top of your controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute routing still exists in Asp.Net Core

```
[Route("Bar")]
public class SomeArbitraryName : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

See [Documentation: Routing to Controller Actions - Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing)

Comment: Thanks @haim770 was adding the link when you did it for me.

Comment: Problem here is that if I have an action `[Route("Bar/edit")]public void IActionResult edit(int id)` then it doesn't route correctly... it will in fact route to `Bar` instead of `Bar/edit`...

Comment: either override the action route `[Route("/Bar/edit")]` or remove bar from the action route so that it inherits the prefix from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own `System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory` and do `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyImpl())` at some point in the application initialization step

Edit: This advice applies to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Core might have different interfaces for something similar

Comment: The OP is asking about Asp.Net Core. Also, `ControllerBuilder` is responsible for construction of known controllers (after routing is done). That's not what is needed here.

Comment: @haim770 seems you are right. i think i need to play a bit with Core :)